# DEFINE statement in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, global-variables, apache-pig

I parsed json input

```
--Load Json 
loadJson =  LOAD '$inputJson' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad=true') AS (json:map []);
```

`'$inputJson'` - is the file having json structure.

Then I parsed json to get some parameters for my pig job

```
--PARSING JSON
--Source : Is the input file I need to process in Pig job
a = FOREACH loadJson GENERATE json#'source' AS ParsedInput;
```

and I stored that in "a". "a" contains the input path ie `/home/sree/foo.txt`

Now I need to load that data into a bag.Next I need to do a normal load statement

```
inputdata = LOAD "/home/sree/foo.txt";
```

Instead of this I have to do

```
inputdata = LOAD a;
```

This is what I am trying to achieve.

So far what I tried is , I used `define`

```
--Source
a = FOREACH loadJson GENERATE json#'source' AS ParsedInput;

-- define a global constant for storage
define myIn "a";

--Load data
inputdata = LOAD "$myIn" ;
dump data;
```

But showing  Unexpected internal error. Undefined parameter : a

How to load that file?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know that pig does not allow the relation to be used in the DEFINE instead of statements.
Refer this,

```
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#define-udfs
```

Comment: How can I achieve this. Any alternatives?

Comment: @Reddevil: I rephrased my question.Please have a look at it.Please tell if you did nt understand

Comment: @SreeVeni..From the post, i think u r extracting values from json fields..Is it correct

Comment: You couldn't use a relations in Define statement instead of Streaming functions and UDF functions.It can't point to the relation specified in the Define statement.